# Not Receiving Response Data (Body or Header) in ISO 8583 using JMeter

Tags: jmeter, response, jmeter-plugins, iso8583, iso8583-1993

I am trying to send ISO 8583 Message Request through JMeter and getting
(channel/HOSTNAME:POST) [receive]  In: 1210 000001 in JMeter Logs
I have left all the fields empty for Response Validation like Timeout and Success Response Field so that no validation rule is applied on response.
But I am not receiving anything in the Response Body or Header through Listener.
Any Idea how can I get the response in Response Body Also.

Comment: Hi usama, is the destination system receiving the request or sending a response at all? Can you specify how are you using JMeter?

Comment: I am using the ISO 8583 Plugin. I have given the iso93ascii packager file along with the port and IP address.

Comment: The server side is receiving the request and generating response accordingly. I have even increased the jmeter logging verbosity and getting this receiving response as [receive]: In 1210 Rest of the Message***

Comment: Can you show your request and response? (update in your question) may be the key is not being matched in the MUX and then JMeter doesn't interpret as the response to the request.

Comment: This is a response to your message in Twitter DM, I just saw it. Please put here the content of the ISO message response, it should be somewhere in the log and should be something like `<isomsg ...> <field id="0" value="1210"` if you don' see it please check the Dmitri response. I'm versed in jPOS, the library used by JMeter for ISO8583, but not so much in JMeter. Once you have the resopnse (and also the request from the log) please past them in the question and maybe I can help you further.

Comment: Hi Andres, my problem got resolved. The issue was JMeter looks for field 11 and 41 to match the response coming from the server. Once I matched those I got my response successfully.

Answer (score 0):

JMeter doesn't display response because it doesn't receive the response and we are not telepathic enough to guess why doesn't JMeter receive the response with the limited amount of information you're giving to us, please refer [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for details

You can use a sniffer tool like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) to see what actually happens with the request and if there is any response.

It's also possible to [increase JMeter's logging verbosity](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-logging) for the ISO 8583 sampler by adding the next line to *log4j2.xml* file:

```
<Logger name="nz.co.breakpoint.jmeter.iso8583" level="debug" />
```

then inspect jmeter.log file and look for messages related to `iso8583` and other suspicious entries

Comment: The thing is, I am response in my jmeter.log as a "Packed Request" but nothing is showing in the Response Data in listener.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting (channel/HOSTNAME:POST) [receive] In: 1210 *STAN Number(field 11) *Identifier (field 41) in my JMeter logs (with increased logging verbosity for ISO 8583 Messages) but could not see any thing in my View Results Tree's Response Data.

Answer:

---

> Field 11 and Field 41 needs to be same in request as well as in
> response. Once I matched both I was able to get response data in
> JMeter successfully.

---